# Does $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ have a singularity at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ have a singularity at infinity?

I know this is equivalent to checking if $\frac{1}{z(e^{1/z}-1)}$ has a singularity at z=0.

But

$z(e^{1/z}-1)=1 + 1/(2z)+1/6z^2 +... \neq 0$ at z=0. Hence I do not believe there is a singularity at z=0.

This means f has no singularity at infinity.

Am I right?

Comment: First learn a definition of a singularity (e.g. the Laurent series expansion has nonzero terms with negative exponent) if you want to answer questions regarding such a concept.

Comment: A non-rational meromorphic function in the plane necessarily has an essential singularity at infinity.

Comment: Indeed $1+1/2z+1/6z^2+\dots\ne0$ at $z=0$. But the series diverges which means that that “sum” is not equal to anything and there *is* a singularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But

$$\frac1{z\left(e^{1/z}-1\right)}=\frac1z\cdot\frac1{1+\frac1z+\frac1{2z^2}+\ldots}=\frac1z\cdot\frac1{1+\frac1z+O\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)}=$$

$$=\frac1z\left(1-\frac1z+\frac1{z^2}-\ldots\right)\ldots$$

and we can see there are infinite *negative* powers in the above (Laurent) series, thus infinity is an **essential** singularity of the original function

Comment: How did u get from the third step to the fourth step?

Comment: @usere5225321: Geometric series expansion.